# Assistance with Node.js functions integration in Apache Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, apache

Here is a short overview to help you experts understand the situation I am in - sorry that its too verbose, but it might help resolving this issue:

So I have a Linux machine, and it runs Apache properly.
Under '/var/www/html', I put my project files which are HTML (index.html) , and a javaScript file with utility functions.

httpd runs and everyone can view the content when 'http:///index.html' from their PC's. 
I want to run a bash script from my Linux machine by letting the users provide the parameters from the front end user interface.

Reading how to do that, I saw tons of examples of how node.js can do that, so I downloaded Node.JS to my Linux machine, and it can be run from:
"
~/Desktop/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64/bin/node --version
v4.2.1
 ~/Desktop/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64/bin/npm --version
2.14.7
"
So it seems like its properly installed...
Note: I did not put anything in my Linux path after extracting the node.js tar.gz file.

Now, from my Linux machine, under '/var/www/html' , I have an HTML file, and I created an 'onclick' event to invoke a javascript function, in which I wrote a call to run this bash script which is located in my Linux machine under "/" - here it is:

function start_run(pTopoFile, pEmailAddress) {

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var  run_command;

 run_command = childProcess.exec('/run.sh ' + pTopoFile + ' ' + pEmailAddress, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
   if (error) {
     console.log(error.stack);
     console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
     console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
   }
   console.log('Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);
   console.log('Child Process STDERR: '+stderr);
 });

 ls.on('exit', function (code) {
   console.log('Child process exited with exit code '+code);
});
```

}

When I run the above I get this error:
"**ReferenceError: require is not defined**"

Which means that even though Node.js was installed properly (as I showed you above), I cannot access its methods from /var/www/html on my Linux machine ...

Can anyone let me know how to link between the great features that node.js has to my scripts?

I hope that I was clear enough with the info I provided...

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: You cannot call Node functions from your client. When you serve JavasScript from apache, the browser that's loading that JavaScript is not connected to your linux machine, it's running that JavaScript on *their* machines in the browser. If you want to be able to run commands on your linux machine from browser based events, you need to have a NodeJS server running and send commands over the wire by using something like [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - so in that case there is no way for me to use node.js to what I need...

I saw the ajax can have this capability -  so Ill try to use that in my script